# Best way to add load more animation like Facebook news?

Tags: swift

I'd like to make my TableView has load more animation like Facebook news with an indicator activity animating at the bottom.

Any guidance for me to do that? Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to make that

- Add a cell with activity at the last `indexPath`
- Add an activity indicator as the `tableFooterView`

I prefer the second approach.

Create your animating view

```
lazy var indicatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
        indicator.startAnimating()
        view.addSubview(indicator)
        indicator.center = view.center
        return view
}()
```

Then set it as the tableFooterView whenever you want to show the bottom animating.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.indicatorView
```

Comment: Thank @Jacob, love the way to set footer!